# On Ubuntu 18.04 windows become inaccessible from Dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome, dock

For example, I can have 2 Chromium windows and I can Alt-Tab between them but there is only one orange dot near the Chromium icon on the dock.

[image: Screenshot]

On the screen shot we see 2 shell windows and 2 orange dots near the shell icon on the dock.
We also see 2 chromium windows and only ONE orange dot near chromium icon on the dock.
Somehow one of the chromium windows is not registered with dock!

Comment: Just added screenshot

Comment: @N0rbert thanks for the assist with screenshot